# ImmutableMap not found in a maven project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, collections

I have a java project with this pom.xml in  IntelliJ that uses Collections

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.collections/google-collections -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I have run this from the command line:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

but even this I got this compilation error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol ImmutableMap
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you project wasn't detected as Maven. Please try to reimport it selecting pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Maven projects
```

You can click on the left most button to reimport all maven projects.

Then run `mvn clean install`.

### *Open your project as a Maven Project*

If you don't find the maven toolbar, your project has to be open as a maven project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In your maven project panel try :

1. Reimport all Maven projects
2. Generate Source and Update Folders for all projects

You should perform a `mvn clean install` before

Comment: I don't see this panel

Comment: You can activate it in View -> Tool Windows -> Maven projects